# jQuery: running 2 different jQuery versions on the same website?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can I run 2 different jQuery versions on the same website and avoid conflicts ?

please don't ask me why.. it is a long story.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe so, but sorry I have to ask: Why want you to do this?

Comment: to be tehnical, yes you could on the same "site," but you would have conflict issues if you loaded two different versions on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html knows only know what you tell it, so if you have something like this in your HEAD section

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**instead** of the below on a given page in your website there shouldn't be a problem.

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, I would not try to reference both versions from any given page as I would expect that to invite method name collisions...

Answer (score 2):

well it should be possible, you will have to update your scripts though.

The idea is not all that difficult: include the least often used version first

then add this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.jQueryOld = jQuery;
</script>
```

then add the more often used version.

now you only have to update your scripts that use the old (or new version withchever it is) to use not the $ or jQuery variable, but the jQueryOld variable

Comment: You probably should add jQuery.noConflict(); to start of the script block, to release control of `$` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Different versions you would get problems. define the includes in the head. You can use obviously different plugins/addons.